# Manipulating the GETDATE function to display DD MM YY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have been trying to manipluate the `getDate`function in SQL but I want the date to come out as todays date and look exactly like this 07-Jan-15 but I cant't get it to work and I have tried everything!

What I have at the minute is:

```
convert(varchar(104), GETDATE()) as [Date]
```

but that is giving me **Jan  7 2015  1:52PM** and thats not what I'm looking for! I have tried all the convert options! So any help with this matter would be appreciated

Comment: There isn't any built in support for this in the 2008 version - you can either do some bodging together of strings or (recommended) take formatting concerns far away from the database - there's usually far better formatting tools available in whatever is *consuming* this data. Keep date-time data as `datetime` (or `datetime2` or `date`, etc) in the database and don't think about strings at all at that level.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the database?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT replace(convert(NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '-') as [Date]
```

**Output:- 07-Jan-2015**

OR

```
SELECT replace(LEFT(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106),6) + '-' + 
       RIGHT(year(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106)),2), ' ', '-') as [Date]
```

**Output:- 07-Jan-15**

Comment: Actually it still says 2015 instead of 15!